# How to improve the update?

Tags: database, postgresql

#### description

I use Postgres together with python3

There are 17 million rows in the table, the max ID 3000 million+

My task is `select id,link from table where data is null;`.And do some codes them `Update table set data = %s where id = %s`.

I tested a single data update needs `0.1s`.

#### my thoughts

The following is my idea

- Try a new database, I heard `radis` soon.But i don't know how to do.

In addition,what is the best number of connections?

I used to made 5-6 connections.
Now only two connections, but better.One hour updated 2million data.

Comment: Do you have an index on `id`? Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**.  [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I have also no idea what you mean with "*crawling data returned to the data*" or "*the main data can not identify whether the crawl*". What is the "main" data? Do you mean the _table_? What exactly do you want to "return"? And what exactly do you need to "identify"

Comment: `id` is the primary key.I think it should have an index.I've edited my question.Sorry for just careless.

Comment: Is your problem with the select or the update? What do you mean by "some codes"? Where is the explain plan?

Comment: The update.I think the update needs 0.1s is too long.Some codes means according to the link fetching data.

Comment: Again: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

If there is any way you can push the calculation of the new value into the database, i.e. issue a single large `UPDATE` statement like

```
UPDATE "table"
SET data = [calculation here]
WHERE data IS NULL;
```

you would be much faster.

But for the rest of this discussion I'll assume that you have to calculate the new values in your code, i.e. run one `SELECT` to get all the rows where `data IS NULL` and then issue a lot of `UPDATE` statements, each targeting a single row.

In that case, there are two ways how you can speed up processing considerable:

1. **Avoid index updates**

   Updating an index is more expensive than adding a tuple to the table itself (the appropriately so-called *heap*, onto which it is quick and easy to pile up entries). So by avoiding index updates, you will be much faster.

   There are two ways to avoid index updates:

   - Drop all indexes after selecting the rows to change and before the `UPDATE`s and recreate them after processing is completed.

     This will be a net win if you update enough rows.
   - Make sure that there is no index on `data` and that the tables have been created with a [*fillfactor*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) of less then 50. Then there is room enough in the data pages to write the update into the same page as the original row version, which obviates the need to update the index (this is known as a *[HOT](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT) update*).

     This is probably not an option for you, since you probably didn't create the table with a fillfactor like that, but I wanted to add it for completeness' sake.
2. **Bundle many updates in a single transaction**

   By default, each `UPDATE` will run in its own transaction, which is committed at the end of the statement. However, each [`COMMIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-commit.html) forces the transaction log ([*WAL*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-intro.html)) to be written out to disk, which slows down processing considerably.

   You do that by explicitly issuing a `BEGIN` before the first `UPDATE` and a `COMMIT` after the last one. That will also make the whole operation atomic, so that all changes are undone automatically if processing is interrupted.